# Grep-like tool to find matches in a JSON file returning the matched context

Tags: json, grep

I'm looking for a tool that, like grep, allows me to not only find matches to a json file, but it also returns the context of the match.

I'm aware that with:

```
cat json_file | grep -C30 properties
```

I would get the 30 lines around all matches with 'properties', but I'd like something that would give the surrounding body of the match, at different depth levels.

The following is an example of data.
It would be inside a file called *json_file*

```
{
"dataitem-1":{
    "aliases":{
        "dataitem-morning":{

        },
        "dataitem-evening":{

        }
    },
    "mappings":{
        "dataitem-temp":{
            "properties":{
                "dataset":{
                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "fields":{
                    "properties":{
                        "channel":{
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                            "type":"string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"dataitem-2":{
    "aliases":{
        "dataitem-morning":{

        },
        "dataitem-evening":{

        }
    },
    "mappings":{
        "dataitem-temp":{
            "properties":{
                "dataset":{
                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "fields":{
                    "properties":{
                        "channel":{
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                            "type":"string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the tool to do something like:

```
cat json_file | json_grep -depth=4 'fields'
```

And it should return:

```
{
"dataitem-2":{
    "aliases":{
        "dataitem-morning":{

        },
        "dataitem-evening":{

        }
    },
    "mappings":{
        "dataitem-temp":{
            "properties":{
                "dataset":{
                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "fields":{
                    "properties":{
                        "channel":{
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                            "type":"string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: It might not be the same, but it seems that the command jq allows to slice and filter inside a json.